# Binding DataReader information to a listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a SQL Data Reader to read some values and set some variables as shown here:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    Config.PartNum = dr[0].ToString();
    Config.OrgQty = dr[3].ToString();
    Config.CurrQty = dr[4].ToString();
}
```

I am trying to fill this listbox in WPF, is there an easier way to pass these values to the listbox?

```
<ListBox Name="partSpecs">
   <TextBlock Text=Config.PartNum></TextBlock>
   <TextBlock></TextBlock>
   <TextBlock></TextBlock>
   <TextBlock></TextBlock>
</ListBox>
```

and so on, I just don't know how to pass these values. I tried multiple string propertys and passing them with databinding and it didn't work

Comment: why u need it in a list box? what are u trying to achive

Comment: First piece of advice would be to use an ORM. A micro orm such as Dapper is closest to ADO. All the nasty code casting to a date/string/number using the ordinal is then done for you. You just give it a type ( class ) which has 3 properties, query to run and an array of variables to use as parameters.

Comment: I figured it out by adding the items via c# rather then setting a binding.